# How to update a MongoDB collection based on multiple conditions without looping

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For one of our Node.js app - we've a [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com) collection like this:

```
[
  {
    "field1": {
      "key1": true,
      "key2": false
    }
  },
  {
    "field1": {
      "key1": true,
      "key2": true
    }
  }
]
```

which we need to update with the following logic:

- For each document

  - if the `field1` exists

    - if the `key1` and `key2` are `true`

      - set `field1` to `[key1, key2]`
    - if the `key1` and `key2` are `false`

      - set `field1` to `[]`
    - if the `key1` is `true` and `key2` is `false`

      - set `field1` to `[key1]`
    - if the `key1` is `false` and `key2` is `true`

      - set `field1` to `[key2]`

As you can see I have ***multiple conditions*** here.

I know the following [update command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update):

```
document.update({
    condition
  }, {
    $set: {
      required updates
    }
  }, {
    multi: true
  })
  .then(() => {})
  .catch((err) => {});
```

Or probably I could loop on each document but that's too bare bone. Is there some advanced feature in MongoDB which can handle this?

The problem with this update command is that I cannot have multiple condition statements with multiple corresponding [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set) commands.

So the problem comes down to:

> How to update a MongoDB collection based on multiple conditions and multiple corresponding `$set` commands.

Comment: You can't use calculated values in the update in the first place. Even unconditional update `set field1 to [key1, key2]` where `key1, key2` come from the document itself won't work, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11345